Upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 network issue WWAN-HW 'missing'
I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 and the wifi  stopped working, displaying a question mark on the wifi icon. Same happens with Ethernet cable, same happens with alternative usb stick wifi.
This solution didn't help. Here are some symptoms:
$ nmcli general status
STATE                 CONNECTIVTY WIFI-HW   WIFI    WWHAN-HW WWAN
connected (site only) limited     enabled   enabled missing  enabled

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
enxe4b97ac9c1f4  no wireless extensions.
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11 ESSID: "CAMERBOX_5GHz"
          Mode:Managed Frequency5.18 GHz Access Point: 3C: (etc.)
          Bit Rate=263.3 Mb/s   Tx-Power=23 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0  
          Tx excessive retries:0  INvalid misc:60   Missed beacon:0

 $ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
  [    17.500387] warning: 'iwlist' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for wifi 7 hardware   use nl80211


is a vpn configured on your system?

no vpn on my system

Reboot in recovery mode solved the issue.

See if wifi power management is crashing networking by disabling it,in terminal
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off
WWAN-HW isn't relavent because that is for cellular devices

first lines returns '[connection] wifi.powersave = 2' but the second line 'sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 power off' returns 'power: Unknown host'

Should have been sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off
